# Traversing map in ascending or descending order using same for loop

Tags: c++

I have a map with some entries inside it. I want to iterate for the map in ascending order or descending order based on some condition using the same for loop. How can i do it?

Example:

```
if(x) 
{
    // Traverse in reverse order
    // If i declare rbegin and rend iterator here
} 
else 
{
    // Traverse in ascending order
    // If i declare begin and end iterator here
}
// Now using same for loop how can i achieve this? Below for loop should use either rbegin or begin based on above condition. Is it possible?
for(;;;) 
{
}
```

More Detailed Example :

```
if(getSort() == DESCENDING) {
            std::map<int,int>::reverse_iterator aItrBegin = map.rbegin();
            std::map<int,int>::reverse_iterator aItrEnd = map.rend();
        }
        else {
            std::map<int,int>::iterator aItrBegin = map.begin();
            std::map<int,int>::iterator aItrEnd = map.end();
        }
        for(; aItrBegin!=aItrEnd; ++aItrBegin) // Here aItrBegin and aItrEnd are not accessible
            cout << "Inside output \n";
        }
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, i have tried it. But if i declare the iterator in if else condition then it is not accessible in for loop. I do not want to put the for loop inside condition statement. That will duplicate my code.

Comment: Best is not to use a loop at all

Comment: Look up `begin()` vs `rbegin()`..

Answer (score 5):

Move your loop logic into lambda instead:

```
 auto logic = []( const auto &p ) {
      // loop logic
 };

 if( x ) std::for_each( map.rbegin(), map.rend(), logic );
 else std::for_each( map.begin(), map.end(), logic );
```

or if you need it often enough implement your own `for_each` template function with parameter, which defines direction.

Comment: Thank you Slava for the answer. Am new to c++11 :) and i will go through lamda expression.
Does calling to lamda expression will be overhead (like calling of function each time from for loop)

Comment: @user6882413 as `std::for_each` is a template function it should be inlined by compiler if necessary.